# O que há de errado neste CREATE FUNCTION do MySQL?

Tags: mysql

O que há de errado neste create function? Não estou conseguindo descobrir.
Já da erro na primeira linha.

```
CREATE FUNCTION SEQ_NEXT_VAL() 
RETURNS INT 
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE retorno INT;

  SELECT MAX(IDE_ERROR) INTO retorno FROM ERROR_LOGGING;
  IF retorno = NULL THEN
    retorno = 1;
  ELSE
    retorno = retorno + 1;
  END IF;

  RETURN retorno;
END;
```

Comment: E qual o erro informado? Terá que [edit] a pergunta com os detalhes para podermos ajudar.

Comment: ERROR 1064(42000): you have an error in SQL syntax near '' at line 5

Comment: falta o `delimiter`, faz assim: `delimiter $$` e no final da função `end $$`

Comment: @Everson não é esse o problema só faltava o SET das variáveis.

Comment: Veja que nesta outra pergunta - https://stackoverflow.com/q/6740932, o erro é o mesmo comentado desta, e esta faltando *delimiter*, o que foi dito na resposta aceita.

Comment: Veja que nessa pergunta, na pergunta já está com o SET das variáveis, sendo assim faltando o DELIMITER realmente, mas como disse, dependendo de alguns editores eles fazem isso automatico

Answer (score 0):

Faltou o set das variáveis:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS SEQ_NEXT_VAL;
DELIMITER |
CREATE FUNCTION SEQ_NEXT_VAL() 
RETURNS INT 
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE retorno INT;

  SELECT MAX(IDE_ERROR) INTO retorno FROM ERROR_LOGGING;
  IF retorno = NULL THEN
    SET retorno = 1;
  ELSE
    SET retorno = retorno + 1;
  END IF;

  RETURN retorno;
END
|
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: funciona assim, dependendo do edito de SQL que você está usando, porém da pra colocar sim.

Comment: estou usando o command line mesmo

Comment: agora ta dando erro na linha 1 no declare

Comment: @BicaBicudo editei com DELIMITER

Comment: com o delimiter $$ deu certo e faltava o set também

Comment: o que você coloca no DELIMITER é indiferente você só esta trocando o delimitador do MySQL nesse momento

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69572/discussion-between-arllondias-and-bicabicudo).